# Perl hashes with value as array

Tags: perl, perl-hash

I have an input file like below:

```
start
f1="apple"
f2="banana"
f3="berry"
end
start
f1="guava"
f2="banana"
f3="berry"
end
start
f1="apple"
f2="cucumber"
f3="orance"
end
```

I am planning to create a hash with values as arrays.

All the tags will be in a temporary array and and in between the tags there is a field `f1` whose value will be the key of the hash.

From start to end it will be stored in temporary array, and once the end is reached, the array is pushed as a value of hash with key as the value found after the latest string `f1=`

I have written the following code but it does not work.

Could anyone suggest any correction here?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

use Data::Dumper;

open( FILE, "<", "temp2" );

my %FILEDATA;
my @tmp   = ();
my $fruit = "";

while ( <FILE> ) {

    chomp( $_ );
    push @tmp, $_;

    my @linefields = split( '=', $_ );

    if ( $linefields[0] =~ /f1/ ) {
        $fruit = $linefields[1];
    }

    if ( $_ =~ /end/ ) {

        if ( $fruit eq "apple" ) {

            if ( exists $FILEDATA{"apple"} ) {
                push( @{ $FILEDATA{"apple"} }, @tmp );
            }
            else {
                $FILEDATA{"apple"} = @tmp;
            }
        }
        elsif ( $fruit eq "guava" ) {

            if ( exists $FILEDATA{"guava"} ) {
                push( @{ $FILEDATA{"guava"} }, @tmp );
            }
            else {
                $FILEDATA{"guava"} = @tmp;
            }

        }

        undef @tmp;
    }
}

print Dumper( \%FILEDATA );
```

Comment: `$FILEDATA{"apple"}=@tmp;` assigns the number of elements in `@tmp` to the has element. You can't put an array in a has (only scalars), but you could put a reference to an arrayy in a hash

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is homework

Here are some guidelines

- `$_` is the default parameter to many Perl operators. In particular, `chomp( $_ )` may be written as `chomp`, `split( '=', $_ )` should be `split /=/`, and `if ( $_ =~ /end/ ) { ... }` can be `if ( /end/ )`
- There is no need to test the value of `$fruit`. If its value is the key that you want then you should use `$FILEDATA{$fruit}`
- `$FILEDATA{"apple"} = @tmp` sets `$FILEDATA{"apple"}` to the *number of elements* in `@tmp`. You need to set it to a reference to the array, with `$FILEDATA{"apple"} = \@tmp`
- There is no need to check whether a hash or array element exists before using `push`. If you just `push @{ $FILEDATA{apple} }, 'ff'` then the array will be created
- `if ( $linefields[0] =~ /f1/ )` tests whether `$linefields[0]` *contains* the string `f1`. To test for equality you want `if ( $linefields[0] eq 'f1' )`
- You shouldn't empty an array or a hash with `undef @data` or `@data = undef`. The correct way is `@data = ()`. To empty a scalar, use `$val = undef`

Here's how your code should look

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

open FILE, "<", "fruit.txt";

my %data;
my @tmp;
my $fruit;

while ( <FILE> ) {

    chomp;
    push @tmp, $_;

    my @fields = split /=/;

    if ( $fields[0] eq 'f1' ) {
        $fruit = $fields[1];
    }

    if ( /end/ ) {
        push @{ $data{$fruit} }, [ @tmp ];
        @tmp = ();
    }
}

print Dumper( \%data );
```

#### output

```
$VAR1 = {
          '"guava"' => [
                         [
                           'start',
                           'f1="guava"',
                           'f2="banana"',
                           'f3="berry"',
                           'end'
                         ]
                       ],
          '"apple"' => [
                         [
                           'start',
                           'f1="apple"',
                           'f2="banana"',
                           'f3="berry"',
                           'end'
                         ],
                         [
                           'start',
                           'f1="apple"',
                           'f2="cucumber"',
                           'f3="orance"',
                           'end'
                         ]
                       ]
        };
```

And here's how I would write it

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use Data::Dumper;

my $file = 'fruit.txt';

open my $fh, '<', $file
    or die qq{Unable to open "$file": $!};

my ( %data, @block, $fruit );

while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {

    chomp $line;

    push @block, $line if @block or $line eq 'start';

    $fruit = $1 if $line =~ /^f1="(\w+)"/;

    if ( $line eq 'end' ) {
        push @{ $data{$fruit} }, [ @block ];
        @block = ();
        $fruit = undef;
    }
}

print Dumper \%data;
```

Note that you shouldn't empty an array or a hash with `undef @data` or `@data = undef`. The correct way is `@data = ()`

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
my $file = 'fruits.txt';
my %hash;


open (my $fh, '<', $file) or die "Could not open $!";
while(my $line = <$fh>) {
  next if $line =~ /start/;
  next if $line =~ /end/;

  if ($line =~ /f1/) {
     my ($key, $val) = split /=/, $line;
     push @{$hash{$key}}, $val;
   }

   if ($line =~ /f2/) {
    my ($key, $val) = split /=/, $line;
    push @{$hash{$key}}, $val;
   }

   if ($line =~ /f3/) {
    my ($key, $val) = split /=/, $line;
    push @{$hash{$key}}, $val;
   }

}

print Dumper(\%hash);
```